# Error Code: 1452 on UPDATE MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I've got a problem which drives me crazy. I searched on the internet but all i could find was: The data on which the foreign key references, is not inserted. Well, I checked it like 100 times, they are inserted.

My tables are:

Stundenanfrage:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stundenanfrage(
LehrerKuerzel CHAR(10),
Anfangszeit TIMESTAMP,
Endzeit TIMESTAMP,
StundeGehalten TINYINT,
Akzeptiert TINYINT,
Lernprozess TEXT,
Sterne INT, -- 1-5 1 schlecht; 5 gut
BetrauNr INT REFERENCES ILB_Betrauung(BetrauNr),
PRIMARY KEY(LehrerKuerzel, Anfangszeit, Endzeit, BetrauNr),
FOREIGN KEY(LehrerKuerzel, Anfangszeit, Endzeit) REFERENCES Lehrerzeiten(LehrerKuerzel, Anfangszeit, Endzeit)
);
```

Lehrerzeiten:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lehrerzeiten(
LehrerKuerzel CHAR(10) REFERENCES ILB_Lehrer,
Anfangszeit TIMESTAMP ,
Endzeit TIMESTAMP ,
Einzelunterricht TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
Thema VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY(LehrerKuerzel, Anfangszeit, Endzeit)
);
```

And ilb_betrauung:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ILB_Betrauung(
BetrauNr INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
LehrerKuerzel CHAR(10) REFERENCES ilb_lehrer,
MatNr CHAR(20) REFERENCES fw_schueler,
zweckmaeßig_erachtet_Lehrer TINYINT,
zweckmaeßig_erachtet_Schueler TINYINT,
Betrauung_AV TINYINT,
Eltern_informiert TINYINT
);
```

The inserted data:

[image: Inserts]

My update query looks like this:

```
UPDATE stundenanfrage SET Akzeptiert = 1  
WHERE LehrerKuerzel = "bb" AND Anfangszeit = "2017-02-20 12:20:00" AND  
Endzeit = "2017-02-20 13:00:00";
```

and threw an error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_ilb`.`stundenanfrage`, CONSTRAINT `stundenanfrage_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`LehrerKuerzel`, `Anfangszeit`, `Endzeit`) REFERENCES `lehrerzeiten` (`LehrerKuerzel`, `Anfangszeit`, `Endzeit`)
```

I also joined all tables and selected that particular record I wanted to update:

```
SELECT * FROM  stundenanfrage s
JOIN lehrerzeiten l ON s.Lehrerkuerzel = l.Lehrerkuerzel AND s.Anfangszeit =  
l.Anfangszeit AND s.Endzeit = l.Endzeit
WHERE l.LehrerKuerzel = "bb" AND l.Anfangszeit = "2017-02-20 12:20:00" AND  
l.Endzeit = "2017-02-20 13:00:00" AND s.BetrauNr = 1;
```

The output was that one record I wanted to update. I also asked my teacher about this error and she had no clue either.

Comment: Remove constraint first then update ,  after update create constraint

Comment: @SinghKailash what's the point of having a constraint if you remove it before making a change? Not to mention the fact that on a big table removing and re-creating a constraint could take quite a lot of time. So, this is a very bad, even harmful suggestion!

Comment: Maybe you have trigger on that table and it is changing some values on update? That error makes no sense otherwise.

Comment: It's not strictly related to the question, but I would not use start and end time in a foreign key. I would add an auto increment field to the `Lehrerzeiten` table to identify each lesson, would make this the PK, and would reference this key in the foreign key from `Stundenanfrage` table.

Comment: 1. Transfer all Record to Temp_table.  then Truncate Orginal table. 2. Temp_table update record.  3. Transfer all Record from  Temp_table To Orginal table.  "Not find other solutions because fields affecting the foreign key when you update record"

Comment: @SinghKailash your suggestions do not make any sense

Comment: @SHADOW Shouldn't the update statement have a join to LehrerKuerzel?

Comment: Can you publish sample data as text ?

Comment: @P.Salmon no, there is no need for join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `Extra`:

```sql
mysql> DESC `Stundenanfrage`;
+----------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| LehrerKuerzel  | char(10)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| Anfangszeit    | timestamp  | NO   | PRI | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| Endzeit        | timestamp  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| StundeGehalten | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Akzeptiert     | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Lernprozess    | text       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| Sterne         | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| BetrauNr       | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See: [12.3.5 Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Try:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stundenanfrage (
  LehrerKuerzel CHAR(10),
  Anfangszeit TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  Endzeit TIMESTAMP,
  StundeGehalten TINYINT,
  Akzeptiert TINYINT,
  Lernprozess TEXT,
  Sterne INT, -- 1-5 1 schlecht; 5 gut
  BetrauNr INT REFERENCES ILB_Betrauung(BetrauNr),
  PRIMARY KEY(LehrerKuerzel, Anfangszeit, Endzeit, BetrauNr),
  FOREIGN KEY(LehrerKuerzel, Anfangszeit, Endzeit)
  REFERENCES Lehrerzeiten(LehrerKuerzel, Anfangszeit, Endzeit)
);

mysql> DESC `Stundenanfrage`;
+----------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| LehrerKuerzel  | char(10)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| Anfangszeit    | timestamp  | NO   | PRI | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| Endzeit        | timestamp  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| StundeGehalten | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| Akzeptiert     | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| Lernprozess    | text       | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| Sterne         | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| BetrauNr       | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Good spot! I had the feeling that it was due to the timestamps, but could not get my head around it

Comment: Thank you very much!! I didn't know that this is default. It works now.

Comment: @SebastianP. it did because it removed the timestamps from the equation :)